# Using '*" to loop through a Generator

Tags: python, list-comprehension, generator

This program works well by printing numbers from 2000 to 3200 which are divisible by 7 and not by 5 separated by a comma

```
print(*(i for i in range(2000, 3201) if i%7 == 0 and i%5 != 0), sep=",")
```

I can understand (i for i in range(2000, 3201) if i%7 == 0 and i%5 != 0) creates a generator object and i can loop it through a for loop. But this '*' symbol does the same. How to understand this?

Comment: What happens when you remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "*" is asterisk operator.
In python, if we put an asterisk before an list/tuple or any iterable object, we can **unpacking the iterable**.
example:

```py
print(*[1, 2, 3, 4], sep=", ")
```

output:

```py
1, 2, 3, 4
```

In your case, the iterable is a generator `(i for i in range(2000, 3201) if i%7 == 0 and i%5 != 0)`